# Add N Number of Radio buttons in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I want to add radio buttons based on some value. Value defines the total number of radio button that i have to show. Currently i am adding two radio button dynamically but this is not a proper solution for me to adding the Radio buttons. If i have to show 10 radio buttons for this code i have to create 10 instances of radio buttons. Can anyone please suggest me how can i achieve this.

code:-

```
class FragmentQues : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentques_layout, container, false)
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Create RadioButton programmatically
    val radioButton1 = RadioButton(activity)
    radioButton1.layoutParams= LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    radioButton1.setText("No")
    radioButton1.id = 1

    val radioButton2 = RadioButton(activity)
    radioButton2.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    radioButton2.setText("Yes")
    radioButton2.id = 2

        profile_radio_group.addView(radioButton1)
        profile_radio_group.addView(radioButton2)

        profile_radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->

            if (checkedId ==1){
                // Some code 
            }else{
                 // Some code 
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: You can e. g. use a loop and store the radio button objects in an Array.

Comment: i was trying this,  can you please give me some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This can be done through a simple for loop

```kotlin
class FragmentQues : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentques_layout, container, false)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val value = 2;
        // If you have custom text for each button you have to define them in a list
        val textList = listOf("No", "Yes")
        
        for(i in 0 until value){
            // Create RadioButton programmatically
            val radioButton = RadioButton(activity)
            radioButton.layoutParams= LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            radioButton.setText(textList[i])
            radioButton.id = i

            profile_radio_group.addView(radioButton)
        }
        

        profile_radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->

            if (checkedId ==1){
                // Some code 
            }else{
                // Some code 
            }
        }
    }
```

- Note that the text has to be passed as an array to match your needs as described in the code